# Add autoNameResolution in Apache CXF plugin in pom.xml

Tags: cxf-codegen-plugin

How to add autoNameResolution in Apache CXF plugin in pom.xml? I have tried to add in defaultOptions tag as well as wsdlOption tag but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in APACHE CXF plugin,

kindly use as below :

```
                           <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
                          <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                       </defaultOptions>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `extraargs` for this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>                        
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/arfolyamok.asmx.xml</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/arfolyamok.asmx.xml</wsdlLocation>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
                <additionalJvmArgs>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</additionalJvmArgs>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```